# Trying to create a Master Plan. Dates and duration of some projects change when inserted as a Sub-project

Tags: ms-project

Trying to make a Master Plan on MS Project.

Some sub-projects were inserted with no issues, but for other sub-projects both the **work effort and Duration change.** 
Is there a reason for this? If you see the images below, for instance the overall Work effort decreases from 225 to 182 and duration changes as well.

[01. Project Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSbPz.png)
[02. Project Plan inserted as sub-project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVyje.png)

EDIT: Added Critical Path images

[image: Original Project plan] 
[image]

If I try to change this in the inserted Sub-project, then the calculations are off. For instance if i put work to 3 days (resource at 80%), the duration comes as 4.62 rather than 3.75. Even if i put the resource at 100%, the work and duration still don't match.

Could someone please help me with this?

Link to Plan - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgjIwYECazJVkUx7-SG8ek-7xq0b?e=C4PtzQ

Comment: Hi Michael Keitch, welcome! The link to the plan redirects to something that doesn't exist or isn't available atm. Also, I'm wouldn't download anything placed in an SO question...

Comment: Hi. In that case, any advice on the best way to upload a MS Project Plan?

Comment: Michael, can you please check a critical path for both options? Is it the same?

Comment: To upload where?

Comment: Somewhere which allows me to link it to the Original post.

Comment: @AndriiH. Criical path highlighted. Seems to be similar except one resource not being highlighted. Could that mean anything?